# 'Git could not checkout' error  is causing problem while deploying an app on engineyard

Tags: git, git-submodules, engineyard

I'm trying to deploy an app on engine yard. I'm using rails 2.3.5 and ruby 1.8.7

When I try to deploy it,

```
~> Deploying revision 481f05e emergency commit
:: running git checkout -q '481f05e42f3e13b5eda7e598a1b797b031c9ca5e'
:: running git submodule sync
Synchronizing submodule url for ''
:: running git submodule update --init

No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path 'school'
No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path 'school'
*** [Error] Git could not checkout (481f05e42f3e13b5eda7e598a1b797b031c9ca5e) ***
```

Is the git submodule sync causing the problem?

I do not have any submodules in my repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I do not have any submodules in my repository.

That means you shouldn't see any `.gitmodules` file in your repo.
If there is, that means that you have somehow a submodule declared (in which case [you might want to remove it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260748/how-do-i-remove-a-git-submodule)).

If there isn't any .gitmodules file, then something within the school path makes the deployment script believe it is a submodules, and tries to access the (non-existent) `.gitmodules` file of the parent repo.
May be `school` has a `.git` directory in it?

Comment: There isn't any `.gitbmodules` file in my repo.

Comment: @CodeMaster123: so it is the reverse issue: something within the '`school`' path makes Git believe it is a submodules, and it looks for a reference in the (non-existent) `.gitmodules` file. (Btw, it is `.gitmodules`, not `.gitbmodules`: that was a typo)

Comment: But there is not `.gitmodules` in my repo. Might it be causing the problem?

Comment: @CodeMaster: well if school is actually a git repo (and has a `.git` inside it), then yes, it could be an issue.

Comment: I created a new repo for a different app and there was this .gitmodules file so it means that my git is working properly. Is there a command which will generate this file or should I create it manually?

Comment: @CodeMaster: this should be the command `git submodule` http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-submodule.html

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing this as well, but had a different solution.  Simply, gemfile was referencing a version on github, but I had failed to push the latest commits online.  So once I made sure all my subrepos were up to date, it was able to checkout.